# Getting the name of point in chart series

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Hi I can't seem to get the names of my chart it always returns S1P1. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

```
Dim pointNames As String
Dim pointEntryIndex As Integer
            For pointEntryIndex = 1 To ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
                ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(pointEntryIndex).Select
                pointNames = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(pointEntryIndex).Name
                Debug.Print pointNames
            
            Next pointEntryIndex
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you really want to do? As far as I see, the name property of a point of a chart series is created automatically in the form SxPy (with x = series number and y = point number). It is a read only property. Do you mean the `DataLabel` of a point? Or the value on the x-axis?

Comment: The datalabel of the point to be able to customize them properly @FunThomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in the comment, the name of a point is in the form SxPy with x = series number and y = point number. This name is given by Excel automatically and cannot be changed (it is a read only property).

You wrote in the comment that you want to access the `DataLabel` of a point. That's rather easy. Every point has a property `DataLabel` - but you need to check if data labels are switched on for that point. For that, you can use the property `HasDataLabel`. If this is `False` and you access `DataLabel`, you will get a runtime error.

You can ensure that data labels are switched on by using the method `ApplyDataLabels` for the data series.

Have a look to the following code. You will notice that I use intermediate variables for chartObject, chart, Series and Point. This is not a must, but it helps to debug the code, and I often use the *Locals Window* (View->Locals Window) to inspect the objects and learn about the properties.

```
Dim co As ChartObject, ch As Chart
' Change this to whatever chart you want to deal with.
Set co = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1)
Set ch = co.Chart

Dim seriesIndex As Long
For seriesIndex = 1 To ch.FullSeriesCollection.Count
    Dim ser As Series
    Set ser = ch.FullSeriesCollection(seriesIndex)
    ' This switches on the DataLabels for the series
    ser.ApplyDataLabels

    Dim pointEntryIndex As Integer
    For pointEntryIndex = 1 To ser.Points.Count
        Dim p As Point
        Set p = ser.Points(pointEntryIndex)
        If p.HasDataLabel Then
            Debug.Print p.DataLabel.Caption
            ' You can set the Caption to whatever you want.
            p.DataLabel.Caption = "Hi" & seriesIndex & "." & pointEntryIndex
        End If
    Next pointEntryIndex
Next seriesIndex
```